# No default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, not-exists

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//To know the car's make, model, color, license number, and the number of minutes the car has been parked
class ParkedCar
{
    string make, model, color, license_number;
    int minutes;
public:
    ParkedCar(string make = "...", string model = "...", string color = "...",
        string license_number = "...", int minutes = 0) : make{ make }, model{model},
        color{color}, license_number{license_number}, minutes{minutes} { this->make = make; }
};

//To know the number of minutes of parking time that has been purchased
class ParkingMeter
{
    int purchased_minutes;
public:
    ParkingMeter(int purchased_minutes) { this->purchased_minutes = purchased_minutes; }
};

//To report the make, model, color, and license number of the illegally parked car
//To report the amount of the fine, which is $25 for the first hour, or part of an
    //hour that the car is illegally parked, plus $10 for every additional hour or
    //part of an hour that the car is illegally parked
//To report the name and badge number of the police officer issuing the ticket
class ParkingTicket
{
    ParkedCar car;
    ParkingMeter meter;
    PoliceOfficer officer;
public:
    ParkingTicket(const ParkedCar &car, const ParkingMeter &meter, const PoliceOfficer &officer)
    {
        this->car = car;
        this->meter = meter;
        this->officer = officer;
    }
};

//To know the officer's name and badge number
//To examine a ParkedCar object and a ParkingMeter object, and determine whether the car's time has expired
//To issue a prking ticket (generate a ParkingTicket object) if the car's time has expired
class PoliceOfficer
{
    string name;
    int badge_number;
    ParkedCar car;
    ParkingMeter meter;
public:
    PoliceOfficer(const ParkedCar &car, const ParkingMeter &meter, string name = "...", int badge_number = 000000)
    {

        this->car = car;
        this->meter = meter;
    }

};
```

So I am making this file for school, and everything is going fine up until I get to the ParkingTicket and PoliceOfficer classes. I am trying to define these constructors and they both tell me that there is no default constructor of the other class. How would I fix this? Thank you! :)

Comment: _"How would I fix this?"_ Provide default constructors, that take no parameters, or have them all set to a default value.

Comment: Are ParkedCar and ParkingMeter really _members_ of a PoliceOfficer? Does a PoliceOfficer really consist of a name, badge, car and meter?

Comment: Yes, `ParkedCar` and `ParkingMeter` really _are_ members of a PoliceOfficer. The name and badge are the PoliceOfficer-specific attrbutes, while I am using in-class copies of the `car` and `meter` objects, received from the constructor, to get their values and functions [that i will make later] for the PoliceOfficer to be able to report that information otherwise not available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your constructor

```
PoliceOfficer(const ParkedCar &car, const ParkingMeter &meter, string name = "...", int badge_number = 000000)
{

    this->car = car;
    this->meter = meter;
}
```

does not have a member initializer for `car` or `meter` (the assignments in the body don't count as initializers), it's as though you wrote `: car(), meter()` initializers, which attempt to call default constructors that don't exist.  You should explicitly write member initializers:

```
PoliceOfficer(const ParkedCar &car, const ParkingMeter &meter, string name = "...", int badge_number = 000000)
    : car(car), meter(meter)
{
}
```

(Also, your object model is a little funny: a police officer has a single parking meter?)

Comment: Yes, in the case that I am using, the officer will only have one parking meter, along with one parked car, and one parking ticket. I can modify the program later to have an array of `ParkingMeter` objects too.

Also, thank you for the help! It now only has 6 errors! :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `ParkedCar` (as you have shown it) *does* have a default constructor (all the arguments have defaults, so it can be called with no arguments.

The real solution is to change the constructor use to use the initializer list:

```
   PoliceOfficer(const ParkedCar &car_, const ParkingMeter &meter_, string name = "...", int badge_number = 000000)
   : car(car_), meter(meter_)
   {
   }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the way you did it, using `car(car_)` and `meter(meter_)` is the same thing as @aschepler mentioned a bit earlier, with the `car(car)` and `meter(meter)` spots, respectively. The parameter names can be the same as the class attributes, yes even if they are class objects, because the parameter name does nothing, but thank you for your response! :)

Comment: He submitted his answer as I was typing mine.  I didn't see his reply before I submitted (but it not surprising we both suggested the same thing - it *is* the "right" answer).   I prefer to avoid using the same name for different things - it may be legal, but I find it confusing.